# Which compiler is standard compliant?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Given this snippet:

```
template <std::size_t Index, typename T, typename ...Args>
typename type_at<Index, T, Args...>::type
get(T t1, Args... args)
{
        return 
                static_cast<type_at<Index, T, Args...>::type>
                (
                        reinterpret_cast<void*>
                        (
                                value_at<Index, T, Args...>::get(t1, args...)
                        )
                );
}


int main()
{
        int   * a     = new int(10);
        double* b     = new double(3.14);
        std::string c = "But I'm a string :(";

        std::cout<< *get<0>(a, b, &c) <<"\n";
        std::cout<< *get<1>(a, b, &c) <<"\n";
        std::cout<< *get<2>(a, b, &c) <<"\n";
}
```

that doesn't work on GCC 4.8.1 but compiles and runs fine in VS2012 with the Nov CTP compiler ( didn't try clang by the way )

Which compiler is right?

[full example](http://ideone.com/ArnDZS)

Comment: clang++ correctly complains about a missing `typename` here: `static_cast<typename type_at<Index, T, Args...>::type>`. g++ also complains about that, but the error message is much less helpful.

Comment: Seems like after adding that typename it works in GCC too... well this is embarrassing :)

Comment: Would be useful to provide at least the error message and your idea why it is/is not right.

Comment: See [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Note that you can cast any object pointer to "pointer to *cv* `void`" using an implicit cast (no `reinterpret_cast` is required).

Comment: @DyP thanks for that, made the code a little bit more readable

Comment: Why do you need that `static_cast` anyway?

Comment: I don't like implicit conversions

Comment: As far as I understand your code, the return type of the global `get` and the `value_at::get` specialization used there are identical. No conversion should be required. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b890639a345f76ee42fb1723d8373cf7-7885f3d27d18134d8479d2ab5250c852)

Comment: You're right again. No idea why I had the impression that I had to cast it. Guess I got lost in the templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case GCC is more standard compliant as you are missing `typename` when referring to a dependent type in `type_at<Index, T, Args...>::type` part of your code.

Clang is also doing a similar thing and gives a nice error message (as always):

```
./test.cc:40:29: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'type_at<Index, T, Args...>::type'
                static_cast<type_at<Index, T, Args...>::type>
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            typename 
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Re "In this particular case": Out of curiosity, is there a way in which MSVC2012 CTP1 is more standards compliant than GCC 4.8.1?

Comment: @Yakk: I don't know. The last time I've seen Windows and/or MSVC was around 2005... :-]